# BenQ PD3220U with 2014 MacBook Pro Retina (USB hub question)

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I want to buy the BenQ PD3220U monitor but I am not sure if I will be able to use it how I intend to. As The following post shows that I should be able to connect to the monitor from my Thunderbolt 2 port using an adapter: [Is Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 (type C) possible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278078/is-thunderbolt-2-to-thunderbolt-3-type-c-possible)
This way I should be able to get 4k 60Hz output. I don't know however if I will also be able to use all it's other features such as the integrated USB hub and KVM switch. Does anybody know if it will work?

Answer (score 0):

If you have another system (PC or Mac) and this 2014 MacBook Pro, you can have a DisplayPort KVM switch to have both systems share the monitor and keyboard/ mouse/ other USB devices.  With the DisplayPort KVM switch, you don't need to have a Thunderbolt 2-to-3 converter.  And you also can get extra USB sharing ports at the same time.

Just carefully to select the right DisplayPort-to-Type-C active converter for the connection between the KVM switch video out to the Type-C monitor.

We tested and recommended CAC-1557 for the cable  and UDP-12AP for the KVM switch.